# usage of slickgrid in MVC3 entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, slickgrid

I would like to use slickgrid in my project to make editing a schedule easy. I downloaded it and found that the documentation in the folder and on the sites i have visited to be very vague. they do not show code as to how you would pull from a database. Does anyone have or know of any examples that show a view, model, and controller for slickgrid implementation? There is an example on code project but it uses data that is not in a database and is very simple in concept.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used slickgrid before but based on the example page [slickgrid example](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/blob/master/examples/example1-simple.html) the following may help get you in the right direction:

```
//Controller
public JsonResult GetSlickGridData()
{
        var slickGridData = db.SlickGridData.ToList();
        return Json(slickGridData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

//View
var data = [];
$.getJSON("/Index/GetSlickGridData", function (items) {
data = items;
});
grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", data, columns, options);
```

So the idea here would be to use the jquery getJSON method to call your controller and bring back the information and store it in data.  Again I'm not too familiar with slickgrid so you may have to also convert 'items' above to a javascript array before assigning it to 'data'.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at spreadsheet example provided by the developer(s)? http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example-spreadsheet.html